# CartThrob price field modifier to minus some amount from cart total

Tags: cartthrob, add-on-development, plugin, extension, shopping-cart

I am having issue in developing cartThrob tax plugin with fieldtype

[image: fsdf]
Tax plugin have this fields.

[image: sdfdf]

I have created a field type that will call that tax settings and populates here.

When I view in frontend everything is good except cart total. In not include in price and add tax to actual price.

[image]
It should be $105 where $100 is price (With tax of $17.36) and $5 shipping

Basically I am looking for a solution to deduct price from cart so I can manually just minus tax amount from subtotal

I tried hook **cart_total_start** but it won’t even call
Don’t know why. Is there any way to call hook in CartThrob?